# Convert string from getline into a number

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a 2D array with vectors. I have a file that has for each line a set of numbers. So what I did I implemented a split function that every time I have a new number (separated by `\t`) it splits that and add it to the vector

```
vector<double> &split(const string &s, char delim, vector<double> &elems) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        cout << item << endl;
        double number = atof(item.c_str());
        cout << number;
        elems.push_back(number);
    }
    return elems;
}


vector<double> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    vector<double> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

After that I simply iterate through it.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file("./data/file.txt");
    string row;
    vector< vector<double> > matrix;

    int line_count = -1;
    while (getline(file, row)) {
        line_count++;
        if (line_count <= 4) continue;
        vector<double> cols = split(row, '\t');
        matrix.push_back(cols);
    }
...
}
```

Now my issues is in this bit here:

```
   while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        cout << item << endl;
        double number = atof(item.c_str());
        cout << number;
```

Where item.c_str() is converted to a 0. Shouldn't that be still a string having the same value as item? It works on a separate example if I do straight from string to c_string, but when I use this getline I end up in this error situation,

hints?

Comment: What is the value of `item` when it goes wrong? (You could use the C++ version, `std::stod` instead of `atof` - which will throw an exception if the input isn't a valid `double` value).

Comment: with std::stod I get `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stod: no conversion
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: If you're getting an error from `stod` it implies your input is not correctly formatted, like perhaps there's an extra tab in there.  Using `stringstream` as in the answer below would avoid that issue as it will skip the extra whitepace.  If you're still having issues then an example of the input it is failing on would be helpful.

Comment: the issue is that I am stuck at the first number of the first line (which happens to be "1")

Comment: Without seeing your input it's hard to guess what the issue is.  This works: [demo](http://ideone.com/a1NTuo) which is basically your main with a split function similar to what was posted in the answer below.  The only difference is input from `cin` rather than a file.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using atof use the stringstream

```
while(!ss.eof())
{
    double number;
    ss>>number;
}
```

EDIT:
I have updated your split function and removed the superfluous return.

```
void split(const string &s, vector<double> &elems) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    while (!ss.eof()) {
        double number;
        ss >> number;
        cout << number;
        elems.push_back(number);
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> columns;
    split("1.32\t1.65\t1.98456\t2.34",columns);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you put that in context? ss has multiple numbers not one how do you go to the next ss?

Comment: I have added how I used it, you might need to check what you are getting when you split out the lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however my question was about a vector in vectors (or 2d array), I manage to get rows not columns